# ldapmodify error 80 olcAccess Handler exited with 1

Tags: openldap

I have an error trying to add an olcAccess using ldapmodify command:

```
ldap_initialize( ldapi:///??base )
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.subtree=“ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=net“ by dn=“uid=hellios,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=net“ write

add olcAccess:
    NOT ASCII (104 bytes)
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcAccess> handler exited with 1
```

The message “NOT ASCII“ is bothering me. Do you think it is related with the error? I can't find where I put a non-ascii character though.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, I'm a new user of macOS and didn't know the “ quotation mark on the xtremeMac keyboard isn't the same as the " quotation mark symbol.

if you want an unofficial bluetooth keyboard it is better to use the mobility lab keyboard.